Restrict Linux Server Port for VPN Deployed in Server Using Docker
I have 2 servers and deployed VPN on server 1 with docker using server 1 IP as VPN IP
Then restrict server 1 and server 2 port using iptables.
This is VPN i used KUY.io Konnect
iptables rules for server 1 & server 2
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s ${SERVER_1_IP} --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
The service using port 8080 deployed in docker with network_mode host
The problem : I can access server 2 port 8080 from VPN but not server 1

Even though the VPN is deployed on the server and using its IP address, it accesses from a Docker container, so it uses the Docker network. After I allowed the VPN container network, it was solved.
For example:
VPN IPV4 Container Network :  172.20.0.0/16
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 172.20.0.0/16 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
But if you set VPN network mode to host, then you need to check file /etc/hosts, and if there is an address 172.0.1.1, then change it to your public IP address.
